# Unable to import contract. JSON file not being read

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, web3js, truffle

I'm going through a drizzle/truffle introduction tutorial and for some reason my contract that is a json file in the contracts folder is not being read when I import it. I've tried changing the file to a .js file and export it using module.exports or export const data but neither works. When When i write the code w/ a .js extension, the code reader recognizes it but it does not read it. When I use a .json extension, it doesn't pick up on it at all. The documentation says to use .json so I'm not sure what the problem is.

I put this in the truffle-config.js to bring the build files into the react client folder and I'm wondering is this the problem?

```
    module.exports = {

    contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, 
    "client/src/contracts")
   };
```

This is my code for my index.js file

```
  import { Drizzle } from "drizzle";
  import MyStringStore from './contracts/MyStringStore';

 const options = {
   contracts = [MyStringStore],
    web3: {
       fallback: {
           type: "ws",
          url: "ws://127.0.0.1:9545",
      },
    },
  };

 // setup drizzle
 const drizzle = new Drizzle(options);
```

MyStringStore is the variable that is not getting read
I've tried every extension and no extension like I said. The folders are in the right places too.

Comment: When you investigate `MyStringStore` via console.log or otherwise, what is the value? This code looks to me like `MyStringStore` will be an object with a `contracts_build_directory` property. I don't see where you're reading in the contents of a file.

Comment: ok i found it. its just a bug. just don't do npm start before you write your code or it will throw that error

Comment: @walkerSwift if you found the solution, you should answer your own question below.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a bug. I fixed it by scratching the project and setting it up like I had except before writing the client side code I didn't type 'npm start' this time. That might of been what threw the error.